# Forecast on payments for 5 Years

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been given the task of creating a data extract that shows how much money an account will make over the next five years(monthly) based on its current rate of payment.

So using 1 example account that pays £1000 a month, which owes £12,000 overall, I can predict we will get £1000 a month and that in 12 months the payment will be settled and every month from then would carry a zero.

I can't work out how to create an SQL query that gives me that, it needs to look at the balance and last payment received, then create a payment for each future month until that balance is zero.

I think I may be over complicating it, All I have managed to come up with so far is some code that tells me how many months it would take to clear based on the last payment which is basically just a balance divided payment. So as it is I have created a query that gets, last payment, number of months till its paid. What I need to do is get it to use the count of months till paid to create future months?

Desired output:

```
Month|Payment
Jun-14|£1000.00
Jul-14|£1000.00
Aug-14|£1000.00
Sep-14|£1000.00
Oct-14|£1000.00
Nov-14|£1000.00
Dec-14|£1000.00
Jan-15|£1000.00
Feb-15|£1000.00
Mar-15|£1000.00
Apr-15|£1000.00
May-15|£1000.00
Jun-15|£0.00
Jul-15|£0.00
Aug-15|£0.00
Sep-15|£0.00
Oct-15|£0.00
Nov-15|£0.00
Dec-15|£0.00
Jan-16|£0.00
Feb-16|£0.00
Mar-16|£0.00
```

Comment: that's constructive, thanks.

Comment: What about the interest of the money not still payed? If applied the second month you'll have (11000 + (11000 * %) * (1/12)) / 11

Comment: @JerichoTwo5 Maybe you should take the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour which tells you what questions you can and can't ask.